# In Hibernate JPA; OneToMany how can I filter results; as I do not want to delete any data ever

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I do not want to perform delete operations in my webapp. Hence I keep a column Status in all tables which is equal to P if record is deleted.  By default I want that when records are fetched; entities with status = P should not be fetched; i.e. an additional where clause should happen... where status = A ; or status != P.

What is the best way to achieve it using annotations ? I can surely write a manual query..

For example :My User class can have multiple childs. How can we implement so that user.getChilds() does not return childs with status as P

```
User.java
   @OneToMany( mappedBy = "usr",
            targetEntity = Child.class,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
    @OrderBy( "fullName ASC" )
    List<Child> childs;

Child.java:
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    User usr;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Hibernate filters](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-filters), or an additional [where clause](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-collection). A filter can be activated and parameterized at runtime, whereas a where clause can't. But they're both used to apply an additional where clause to a persistent collection.